# How to push empty folder to AzureDevops through visual studio

Tags: azure-devops

I tried few times and failed to push empty folder, any way to push empty folder to azdo from VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, in Git, you cannot commit empty folders, because Git does not actually save folders, only files. You'll have to create some placeholder file inside those directories if you actually have no committable content.

You can refer to this [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) and this official [document](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F).

Answer (score 1):

You can add .gitkeep file inside this directory.

Comment: No, file '.gitkeep' is just placeholder